# How to add custom parameters to Facebook mobile apps events?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I want to send some parameters with my app events in order to use them with my Facebook Dynamic Remarketing, but I have 2 different guides in Facebook documentation about how exactly to send these params.

The first one is this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#add-events

But there is another one here 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/best-practices/ecom-and-retail

where they say to send it like FBSDKAppEvent**ParameterName**

So what is true?

Comment: Above first URL which you have mentioned is working , i have used this in one of my project .

Comment: I know it's working but how can I add custom parameters to that event?